Logo inflation and ripple animation
Trying to figure out how they got this material and made the logo ripple out as in the animation (see homepage for the animation).
So far I've been working with cloth physics, but can't get it to ripple like this and my logo has seams in it, making it look more like a balloon blowing up. Should I be using solid body physics? Wave effect? Any ideas?

https://www.metalab.com

I might try an enclosed cloth with perhaps animating increasing Pressure.   Add Wind force that you can also animate the strength.
